# Handoff from Chrome on Mac to Safari on iPhone

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, iphone, safari

I noticed today while browsing Safari on my iPhone that Chrome popped up in the Handoff spot in the Dock on my Mac. This got me wondering, is it possible to do this the other way around? I like using Chrome for my browser, but have been missing the handoff functionality of it for a while, so seeing this go Safari to Chrome between iPhone and Mac got my hopes up of it going Chrome to Safari between Mac to iPhone.

Does anyone know if this is possible to accomplish? Or is this just a iPhone to Mac only feature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I use Chrome on my Mac and Safari on my iPhone for me it works both ways. Mac to phone and phone to Mac

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain how this set up works and if there are any special considerations the OP has to be aware of?

Comment: how can you do it?